# How to invoke reactive service inside JmsListener without blocking?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-jms

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EventListener {
    
    private final EventProcessingService eventProcessingService;

    @JmsListener(destination = "inputQueue", constainerFactory = "myContainerFactory)
    public void receiveMessage(Message message) {
       eventProcessingService(message).block(); // return Mono<Void>
    }

}
```

I have some Listener that listens to the queue and when messages come in it calls the reactive method of the service (EventProcessingService). I would like to know what happens when I block execution of a reactive service, can this lead to errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your application is the one consuming the messages, the most appropriate would be to call `subscribe()`.

`Subscribe` should be used if your application is the final destination, you have not posted what `eventProcessingService` actually does so can't really tell.

All code can lead to errors, it depends on how your error handling look's like. `Subscribe` itself wont throw any errors, but you can choose to handle errors differently.

[Here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_subscribe_method_examples) you can see different examples on how you wish to handle errors, and if you want to log errors. etc.